# Why are women more susceptible to radiation?

Tags: radiation

The answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-far-could-we-send-someone-before-they-get-a-lethal-dose-of-radiation) on the Space.SE indicates women are more susceptible to radiation in space than men.

[image: Radiation susceptibility in men and women]

Why is this the case? Is it merely that women have less muscle mass (which being more dense than fat) and therefore may receive a greater dose when exposed?

Answer (score 6):

It's actually because of the greater risk "*from breast, ovarian, and uterine cancers*" ([article](http://www.space.com/22252-women-astronauts-radiation-risk.html)).  There's a more scientific write-up [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21574861), and while I don't have access the abstract implies that a more rigorous update of the exposure criteria upheld sex differences.  From a more terrestrial perspective, The Nuclear Information and Resource Service ([nirs.org](http://www.nirs.org)) has [this](http://www.nirs.org/radiation/radhealth/radiationwomen.pdf) rather incensed piece on the issue.  They cite a [2006 NAS report](http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=11340) which

> finds that harm to women (cancer) is 50% higher than the comparable harm to men from radiation doses that fall within the legal limit to the public over a lifetime.

Basically, it looks like females are more likely to get cancer from radiation, and once they do, those cancers are more likely to cause more harm.  [According to the executive summary of NASA's 2014 in-depth report](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/full/10.1089/jwh.2014.4914):

> [A] 45-year-old man has a 344-day limit versus a 187-day limit for a 45-year-old woman, due to radiation exposures on the space station that would be typical at the time of solar maximum.

The effect of body size, however, could be the opposite.  [Taller women get more cancer](http://healthland.time.com/2011/07/21/the-hazards-of-height-tall-people-may-be-more-prone-to-cancers/), with [that study](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanonc/article/PIIS1470-2045%2811%2970154-1/fulltext) showing a 16% increase in incidence for every 10cm (4in) height increase.  That increase, however, is among certain types, such as melanomas, and not the above-mentioned "*breast, ovarian, and uterine cancers*."  Males, being taller, could therefore get more cancer overall; it turns out [males usually die more from most cancers](http://healthland.time.com/2011/07/13/almost-every-type-of-cancer-kills-more-men-than-women-study-shows/), just not (obviously) "*breast, ovarian, and uterine cancers*."